# How to take screen shot of a window in focus in Virtual Box?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, screenshot

The host is running Windows 10. I want to install Windows 10 in virtual Box and take screenshots of the installation screen.

Note that at this point, I can't installed guest editions. I can take screenshot of entire window of VM with Right CTRL + ALT + PrtScn but not the currently focused window.

Is there a way I can screenshot the active window in VM at this stage?

Comment: I forgot if you need guest addons for coherent mode. If so, then its not possible. The only way then would be to use a screenshot program that can draw rectangles, and simply draw what you want to capture. Greenshot can do this. Alternatively, capture the whole screen and use a paint program to crop the image.

Comment: Get screenshots of VMM window. Then use any picture editor which may precise crop in batch processing.

Comment: Use Windows Snipping Tool or SnagIT.  I use the latter, activate the capture in Windows, mouse over to the VM  (or better yet, have the VM screen ready to capture) and capture it.